# Rows and Columns of Html Table Resizable using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to resize the HTML table rows/column Width and height.
Now I am Using separate plugin to adjust column width [Plugin link](http://quocity.com/colresizable/)

And Separate jquery function to adjust rowHeight.

```
$("#MatrixTabletr").resizable();$("#MatrixTable td").resizable();
```

its `working fine in firefox` but `not yet in chrome`.

**Note**:
    Here am saving width of column/height of row and retrieving again by while display the table by C#. please look my code [`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/44fKg/12/)

(I am fixing height 50px as sample I need to reduce size in chrome but firefox working good)
please help me

Comment: your fiddle works well for me in chrome, even after I removed line `height:50px;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to use the jQueryUI to achieve the resizable effect, you have no need to use that colResizable plugin. jQueryUI resizable can do horizontal & vertical resize both.

I comment the code invokes colResizable plugin, It works fine on chrome now.

```
$("#MatrixTable").colResizable({
    onResize: onSampleResized
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mygoare/44fKg/13/