# How to create resizable table on the web?

Tags: web-applications

How to create a table which any row and column is resizable on the web like in Excel Online or Google Sheets? Are they using just simple Javascript and jQuery or is it something else?

Comment: hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690957/rows-and-cloumns-of-html-table-resizable-using-jquery

Answer (score -1):

I think, in Excel Online table made not as table, every cells are divs. And then you can control their size simply with js